# Is Windows 10 Insider Build usable within SOC 2 compliance?

Tags: windows-10, compliance, corporate-policy, windows-11

Or Windows 11 pre-release, just cause I'm curious?

(By employees if that wasn't implicit.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOC 2 does not prescribe any specific operating system, or explicitly prohibit the use of pre-release software. It is much more focused on organisational security practices than specific details like that.

What a compliance assessor would almost certainly want to know is:

- What is your specific justification for using Windows 10 Insider or Windows 11 Pre-Release, instead of a supported build?
- What data is being handled by these systems? What customer information do they have access to?
- What risk assessments have you made about the use of these systems, given their role and level of access to sensitive data?
- What compensating controls have you implemented in order to mitigate those risks?
- If this is a temporary measure, what is your plan for migrating off of insider/beta/pre-release software?

If you can answer those questions in a satisfactory manner, you'll almost certainly be fine.